# ADC 0808/0809 EOC pulse

Tags: adc

What kind of signal does EOC pin of [ADC 0808 and 0809](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/adc0809-n.pdf?ts=1690630015061&ref_url=http%253A%252F%252Fwww.ti.com%252Flit%252Fgpn%252Fadc0809-n) give before and after completion of conversion?(low to high pulse OR high to low pulse)

Comment: You’re asking about a device that was useful maybe 30 years ago, it is not something you’d use in a new design.

Answer (score 1):

See figure 7 of datasheet.

At the beginning of conversion (start), EOC goes low.
At the end of conversion, EOC returns high.
So, after starting the conversion, you have to wait until EOC returns high to get readings.

[image]